# GWT Design wont run

Tags: gwt, gwt-designer

before I have no problem with GWT design, however right now, I am getting this error:

```
Error loading module(s).
GWT Designer can't load a module either because there is not enough heap space available for Eclipse, or some other module or internal error has occurred. The GWT log at $project_dir/.gwt/.gwt-log has the following error messages:

Line 4: Unexpected exception while processing element 'inherits' Failure while parsing XML Unexpected error while processing XML
```

I already added these vmargs with my eclipse.ini but still it wont work:

```
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-XX:PermSize=64M
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
-Xms256m
-Xmx512m
```

I have also run VisualVM and the used up PermGen is not even close the the max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did was to put the CSS on the `com.myapp.css` package (or similar). Which solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm ... looks familiar problem to me.

Don't wish to disappoint you too much, but GWT Designer is non-functional, actually dysfunctional, for complex ui, especially when you try to open a widget that you did not create with GWT Designer. Or one that you created with GWT designer but then you modified using an editor.

GWT Designer, like spring roo, is good only to start you off on a UI - that's my abject opinion. And then when I start introducing complexity to it, and that I had to do it with the source editor, after which when you try to edit the UI with Designer, it would fail to open.

I faced the same problem with C# in Visual Studio. (OK, I am still using Visual Studio 2005).

Once you use the editor on your UI, there is no turning back. Your UI designer would not recognise the design anymore.

I observe that Qt overcomes the issue by not letting you muck around with the generated source code. When you use the designer to modify the UI, it modifies an XML file, which on compilation generates the C++ source file. Changing the generated C++ source file will not change the design because the UI design is stored in the XML file. When you modify the XML file with an editor, you have to modify it compliant to Qt designer'e expectations - and I have to do it only on rare occasions.

One might think that gwt ui.xml template file would function the same way as Qt's UI XML file - the difference is Qt's UI XML file has no C++ template bean behind it and GWT ui.xml file requires a Java template bean behind it. OTOH, unlike GWT or Visual Studio, I do find generating Qt Designer compliant widgets a rather tedious/daunting task.

Comment: I guess you're right. I only use the GWT designed to start the layout--but I dont use it for complex UI. However, I did a trick, which I refactored the UI such that I can still use GWT designer for bits and pieces of the complex UI. And btw, right now I am adopting GWT UiBinder.